# IdentityServer4: [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] not granting access to Admin User even when the JWT Token has {"role": "Admin"} claim

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, identityserver4

My problem is that even when the logged on user is an Admin still he is not able to access the Controller with `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` attribute.

```
Note: The codes works perfectly fine on postman testing but not on openid connect.
```

**IdentityServer 4**

I have my Identity server 4 set up and working great with OpenId connect. No problem with it.

**Client Project**

There is a client probject just having a web api which is secured with `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` attribute.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
......
}
```

It's URL is `https://localhost:5002/WeatherForecast`.

Now: I open this secured URL in the browser, I am redirected to the IdnentityServer login page where I enter the username and password of admin user.

After that what happens is that I am redirected to `https://localhost:5002/Account/AccessDenied?ReturnUrl=%2FWeatherForecast` page (which should not be as user has admin role).

[image]

On the console I get the error -

> Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
> RolesAuthorizationRequirement:User.IsInRole must be true for one of
> the following roles: (Admin)

[image]

On decoding the token on jwt site, I can clearly see `"role": "Admin"`there. See the below image:

[image]

**So I can say My token has Admin role claim on it and it should therefore be able to access the secured controller. *But it does not happen??***

If i remove the roles from attribute attribute - `[Authorize]` then I am able to access the controller with the token. See image below:

[image]

**The Codes:**

The startup.cs ConfigureServices method is the place where I have added the Openid connect codes:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
.AddCookie("Cookies")
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";
    options.Audience = "IS4API";
})
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
    options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";
    options.ClientId = "postman";
    options.ResponseType = "code";
    options.Scope.Add("fullaccess");
    options.SaveTokens = true;
});
```

I am not sharing the codes for IdentityServer because the token is generating property and I don't think there is any problem on IdentityServer.

So what can be the problem here, why roles based IdentityServer 4 authentication failing on my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bring the role claim types into your app. Inside .AddJwtBearer options there's a place to set the role claim type inside the token validation paramters:

```
options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    NameClaimType = "name",
                    RoleClaimType = "role"
                };
```

Then inside the config file in IDS4, add the Jwt claim type "Role" for your app:

```
new ApiScope
        {
            Name = "myAPI",
            DisplayName = "my API",
            Enabled = true,
            UserClaims =
            {   JwtClaimTypes.Name,
                JwtClaimTypes.Email,
                JwtClaimTypes.Subject,
                JwtClaimTypes.Role,
                JwtClaimTypes.Address,
                JwtClaimTypes.Confirmation,
                JwtClaimTypes.EmailVerified,
                JwtClaimTypes.Id,
                JwtClaimTypes.Profile
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's working on postman, in my opinion something wrong in your openid connect configuration. Check the identity server openid connection [documentation](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/3_interactive_login.html)

Comment: Something is wrong on openid configurations on my case. The documneation does not have anything regarding adding of roles. Postman testing is working but no on browser.

Answer (score 0):

This problem will happen for some reason. please check the below steps.

1.The problem can be in the order of `Authentication` and `Authorization` in the pipeline, make sure `Authentication` is placed before `Authorization`.

2.You must add the following line of code in `Startup.cs` to enable RoleManager.

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
   .AddRoles<IdentityRole>() // <-- Add this line
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

3.According to this [GitHub Link](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1813#issuecomment-420066501), Add this line of code to `ConfigureServices`

```
// Add Role claims to the User object
services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>, UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>>();
```

Please check all steps. I think it will help resolve your issue.

Comment: these things i have already done. My solution is working in postman testing but not on openid connect on the browser.

Comment: @yogihosting Maybe you updated your question for that I did not notice that. https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/06/29/oidc-user-auth-aspnet-core I think this link will help you for resolving your issue.